# Linq to check if the datarow exists in a datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have my query as below

```
  DataRow dr = objDtModifier.Rows[num];
  var existingRows = resultDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row == dr);
```

But `existingRows.Count` always returns me zero .

Can anyone tell what's wrong here .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing a row object from the objDtModifier source colloction with a different set of row objects in a resultDataTable collection which will alway return an empty result set as they are a different set of object references (this is regardless of whether they contain the same data or not).
Is there a property you can test against? eg:

```
var existingRows = resultDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Id == dr.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare a row object which you get from a table called `objDtModifier` against a row from a table called `resultDataTable`. So unless that's a typo this is probably what's wrong.

*Edit*: Even if they contain rows from the same database table you are comparing the object references of two different row objects - this will fail. You need to compare two columns which uniquely identify the row (or maybe a set of columns).

Comment: @NitheshKumarKuntady: Yes, they're of the same type - but they're going to be different objects, and `==` isn't overloaded for `DataRow` to provide any sort of value equality.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because row and dr not same object and your are going to compare two object,
try to check columns of row , something like primary keyvalue

Answer (score 0):

No matter if they are same type. If objDtModifier and resultDataTable does not contain same instances the behaviour you get is correct.

row==dr uses equality by reference, like chris stated. if objDtModifier and resultDataTable contains diffrent row instances but refers to same data, you might want to use row.id==dr.id if id is the primary key of the datable.